# ASP.NET Find Control by its Partial ID

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have this div in my html

```
<div class="myValue" runat="server" id="myValueDiv">
            </div>
```

I add my radio button dynamically **to that div** like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl div = null;
foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
            {
numberOfReasons++;

                if ((numberOfReasons % 4) == 1)
                {
                    div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    div.Attributes.Add("class", "oneLine");
                }
                RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
                radioButton.ID = "reason_" + row["reasonName"].ToString();
                radioButton.GroupName = "reason";
                radioButton.Text = row["reasonName"].ToString();

div.Controls.Add(radioButton);
                if (numberOfReasons % 4 == 0)
                {
                    myValueDiv.Controls.Add(div);
                }
                else if (numberOfReasons == results.Rows.Count)
                {
                    myValueDiv.Controls.Add(div);
                }
             }
```

The generated HTML is:

```
<div id="myValueDiv" class="myValue">
            <div class="oneLine"><input id="reason_romaroma2" type="radio" name="reason" value="reason_romaroma2"><label for="reason_romaroma2">romaroma2</label><input id="reason_ss" type="radio" name="reason" value="reason_ss"><label for="reason_ss">ss</label><input id="reason_superroma" type="radio" name="reason" value="reason_superroma"><label for="reason_superroma">superroma</label><input id="reason_asdfasdf" type="radio" name="reason" value="reason_asdfasdf"><label for="reason_asdfasdf">asdfasdf</label></div><div class="oneLine"><input id="reason_asdfa" type="radio" name="reason" value="reason_asdfa"><label for="reason_asdfa">asdfa</label><input id="reason_weqe" type="radio" name="reason" value="reason_weqe"><label for="reason_weqe">weqe</label></div></div>
```

when I click a button, I want to know if the user has selected any button and if yes what is the text of that button

#### What i have tried:

```
var checkedRadioButtons = myValueDiv.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(radButton=> radButton.Checked).ToList();
            if (checkedRadioButtons.Count>0)
```

but the result **of the count** is always `zero`

what did I miss please?

#### Note:

all the radio button has `ID` starts with:

**reason_**

Comment: Its not possible to get values of dynamically generated controls from server side. You need some client side scripting to get that values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add the control dynamically in the init event

and you can use this method to find and get a list of check boxes in a container control and you can edit it to get any type of controls

```
private List<CheckBox> FindCheckControls<T>(Control control, bool recurse)
    {
        List<CheckBox> found = new List<CheckBox>();
        Action<Control> search = null;
        search = ctrl =>
        {
            foreach (Control child in ctrl.Controls)
            {
                if (typeof(CheckBox).IsAssignableFrom(child.GetType()))
                {
                    found.Add((CheckBox)child);
                }
                if (recurse)
                {
                    search(child);
                }
            }
        };
        search(control);
        return found;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get **TEXT** of selected Radio Button:

```
var divcontrols = myValueDiv.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>();
    foreach(HtmlGenericControl loHTML in divcontrols)
    {
        var checkedRadioButtons = loHTML.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(radButton => radButton.Checked).ToList();
        foreach (RadioButton lobtn in checkedRadioButtons)
        {
            Response.Write(lobtn.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I kept having the same problem. the `divcontrols` is empty

Comment: I tried your code with dummy data in my local machine and it works fine