# asp.net postback re render already-dynamically added controlls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I add radio button dynamically when the page load, I want when to click a button on the page to know **what is the selected radio button**. I tried a lot but it seems that when the page is posted back, the dynamically added controlls are gone.

I want to ask if there is a way to re render these controllrs again.

all the controlls have `ID` starts with

**reason_**

I hope you help me, if you want to know my code, i already posted another question here [ASP.NET Find Control by its Partial ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061271/asp-net-find-control-by-its-partial-id) (and please don't flag it as repeated because that one is about partial ID, but now i understood that i have to re render the page again)

#### Update1

After the comments, I wrote this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //here i add the radio buttons automatically
        DataTable results = new DataTable();
        //i fill the results data table from database
        ViewState["numberOfReasons"] = results.Rows.Count;
        foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
        {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
            radioButton.ID = "reason_" + row["reasonName"].ToString();
            radioButton.GroupName = "reason";
            radioButton.Text = row["reasonName"].ToString();
            ViewState["reason_" + numberOfReasons] = row["reasonName"];
        }
    }
}
```

as you see, i saved the number of reasons in the view state, and i save all the reasons in the view state,

this i do this in the page init

```
protected void page_init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        int numberOfReasons = int.Parse(ViewState["numberOfReasons"].ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReasons; i++)
        {
            RadioButton r = (RadioButton)Page.FindControl(ViewState["reason_" + i].ToString());
            if (r.Checked)
            {
                Console.Write("I will not swear on Stack Overflow.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but i got null exception in this line

```
 int numberOfReasons = int.Parse(ViewState["numberOfReasons"].ToString());
```

how to solve that exception please and is this the correct solutioN?

#### Update 2

After the new ansewr, i have to show you where i add my radio buttons, i add every four radio buttons to div like this, and then i add that **new div** to the myValueDiv as this:

```
int numberOfReasons = 0; // a integer variable to know if the number of the reasons becomes able to be divided by four
            HtmlGenericControl div = null;
            foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
            {
                numberOfReasons++;

                if ((numberOfReasons % 4) == 1)
                {
                    div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    div.Attributes.Add("class", "oneLine");
                }

                RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
                radioButton.ID = "reason_" + row["reasonName"].ToString();
                radioButton.GroupName = "reason";
                radioButton.Text = row["reasonName"].ToString();

                div.Controls.Add(radioButton);
                if (numberOfReasons % 4 == 0)
                {
                    myValueDiv.Controls.Add(div);
                    //numberOfReasons = 0;
                }
                else if (numberOfReasons == results.Rows.Count)
                {
                    myValueDiv.Controls.Add(div);
                    //numberOfReasons = 0;
                }
            }
```

Comment: One way to deal with when you first add the controls to the page at that time store the control id's in session/viewstate and in `page init ` check for `postback` and if it is then re add them. This pretty common issue with the dynamically added controls. [This might help you](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35360/ViewState-in-Dynamic-Control)

Comment: @CoderofCode but how? and why in this `page init` not in the `page load`, i mean how to know which radio button has been selected or not

Comment: The page retains it's value from the `viewstate` which will be loaded in `pageload` so before page load you need make sure you have the controls available for that value. Check the link from above comment.

Comment: @CoderofCode so you mean that i have to store my ids in the viewstate and then check for them in the page init when the page is post back right? but my question now will be: to store in view state, i need key and value, the value should be the id, but what the key will be? the same problem i guess because i don't know the key, right?

Comment: Key can be anything you can store like `key:mycontrol`,`value:id` in `INIT` just use the `mycontrol` to get id's and from that get the values from the `viewstate`.

Comment: @CoderofCode but how can I know the keys when the page is post back? the keys will be generated dynamically too right? could you give me a very simple code please?

Comment: @CoderofCode i tried to do what you told me and i write a code, i updated the question with some of the code, could you check please?

Comment: Are your radio buttons in a `RadioButtonList`?

Comment: @HugoYates no they are not, i add them automatically to a div, they have the same radio group, i can show you the code if u want

Comment: Check now it should be there.

Comment: @CoderofCode yes now i receive it, i appreciate it very very much, i am checking now

Comment: @CoderofCode OMG, you are amazing, you are the God of coding, you are the king of programming, you are my God, you saved my life. Thank you very very very very very very very very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working and tested code.

**Aspx Code**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btn_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**CS code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            CreateDynamicControls();
        }
    }
```

Page load will load the controls on first time.

```
    protected override object SaveViewState()
    {
        //save view state right after the dynamic controlss added
        var viewState = new object[1];
        viewState[0] = base.SaveViewState();
        return viewState;
    }
```

[SaveViewState()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.saveviewstate(v=vs.110).aspx) will save the viewstate right after the dynamic controls are added to the page form.

```
    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        //load data frm saved viewstate
        if (savedState is object[] && ((object[])savedState).Length == 1)
        {
            var viewState = (object[])savedState;
            CreateDynamicControls();
            base.LoadViewState(viewState[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            base.LoadViewState(savedState);
        }
    }
```

[LoadViewState()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.loadviewstate(v=vs.110).aspx) will load the data from the maintained viewstate

```
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Make sure only dynamic controls get selected for process
        foreach (Control cntrl in this.Form.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(x => x.ID.Contains("reason")))
        {
            bool option = ((RadioButton)cntrl).Checked;
        }
    }
```

`btn_Click` can be your any postback event this is used by  me demonstrate the postback

Method to create the dynamic controls,

```
    private void CreateDynamicControls()
    {
        List<string> optionList = new List<string> { "opt1", "opt2", "opt3" };
        foreach (string row in optionList)
        {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
            radioButton.ID = "reason_" + row;
            radioButton.GroupName = "reason";
            radioButton.Text = row;
            this.Form.Controls.Add(radioButton);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your answer, i already did that but for got to load the items again in the load view state, anyway, as i updated my question with my real code, i add every four radio button to a div, then i add that div to my `myValueDiv` div, could you please update your `button click` events to find the radio button ? i really appreciate it, i can give you my code if you want, it is very very very easy

Answer (score 0):

I am using simple functionality just to check basic concept using your scenario. I am doing like following :

**ASPX:**

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

CS :

```
 protected void page_init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> TempList = new List<string>();
    TempList.Add("Name1");
    TempList.Add("Name2");
    TempList.Add("Name3");
    TempList.Add("Name4");
    TempList.Add("Name5");
    TempList.Add("Name6");
    ViewState["numberOfReasons"] = TempList.Count;
    int i = 1;
    foreach (string row in TempList)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
        radioButton.ID = "reason_" + i.ToString();
        radioButton.GroupName = "reason";
        radioButton.Text = row;
        ViewState["reason_" + row] = row;
        this.Form.Controls.Add(radioButton);
        i++;
    }
}

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control cntrl in this.Form.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(x => x.ID.Contains("reason")))
    {
        bool option = ((RadioButton)cntrl).Checked;
        if (option)
        {
            Label1.Text = cntrl.ID + " Checked";
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get selected check box even after postback. I don't know where you working wrong. Hope this will help you.