# Maintain State of Dynamically Added DropDownList c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was hoping someone could provide some advice on what I am doing wrong here. I am attempting to dynamically add a series of DropDownList controls that will be populated from the database. I have many other DropDownLists added at design time that are populating from the database and maintaining state across postbacks.

I am only experiencing issues with the dynamically added controls. The issue is that the DropDown control is populating from the database when initially created and is returning empty on postback. (I have set autopostback to true for the DropDownList control so that postback occurs when selected item changes.)

I have read a number of posts and attempted a variety of strategies and nothing has worked so far.

Here is the relevant code:

I have a placeholder to attach the control to.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="DynamicControlsHolder" runat="server" />
```

I use a session variable to hold the number of controls (for my test I am only adding 1 but will need to add several)

```
public int NumberOfControls
{
get { return (int)ViewState["NumControls"]; }
set { ViewState["NumControls"] = value; }
}
```

I call two different methods depending upon whether it is a postback or not.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    this.NumberOfControls = 0;
    addSomeControls();
}
else
{
    this.createControls();
}

protected void addSomeControls()    //done in original page_load so bind data
{

    DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();
    //not using the following event handler yet, so I didn't post the code
    dl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dlOnSelectedIndexChange);

    using (I.DBEntities1 ctx = new I.IDBEntities1())
    {

      dl.EnableViewState = true;
      dl.AutoPostBack = true;
      dl.ID = "ControlID_" + NumberOfControls.ToString();
      dl.DataSource = ctx.Lk_PersonPersonAssocType.OrderBy(c => c.Assoc_Type);
      dl.DataValueField = "ID";
      dl.DataTextField = "Assoc_Type";
      dl.DataBind();
    }

    DynamicControlsHolder.Controls.Add(dl);
    this.NumberOfControls++;
}

protected void createControls()   //postback
{
        int count = this.NumberOfControls;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();

            dl.ID = "ControlID_" + NumberOfControls.ToString();

            DynamicControlsHolder.Controls.Add(dl);

        }
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am creating these controls dynamically. So, my understanding is that they no longer exist after postback.

Comment: This question is answered number of times [here is one wanswer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073687/asp-net-postback-re-render-already-dynamically-added-controlls/29076146#29076146). How to maintain and get vvaleus from dynamically added controls.

Comment: andricadar, it DynamicControlsHolder.FindControl("ControlID_" + NumberOfControls.ToString()) returns null on postback.

Comment: @adricadar, thank you for the assistance. I added createControls() to OnInit  for IsPostback and I get a nullReferenceException for NumberOfControls session variable.

Comment: @adricdar, I converted NumberOfControls to Session and that eliminated the nullReferenceException. I moved the createControls() to OnInit PostBack and unfortunately I still get an empty list on post back.

Comment: I see that onpostback, DynamicControlsHolder has no controls. Perhaps I need to persist DynamicControlsHolder is a ViewState variable.

Answer (score 0):

I now have things working and wanted to post the answer in the event this it will assist others. @dricdar, thanks for your help. Aspects of your feedback assist in solving the problem.

I moved the call to createControls() into OnInit.
I changed NumberOfControls to a session variable:

```
public int NumberOfControls
{
  get { return (int)Session["NumControls"]; }
  set { Session["NumControls"] = value; }
}
```

In OnInit, onPostBack I call createControls().
In Page_Load, !isPostBack, I set NumberOfControls to zero and call addSomeControls();

The methods now look as follows;

```
protected void addSomeControls()    //done in original page_load so bind data
    {
        DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();
        dl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dlOnSelectedIndexChange);

        dl.EnableViewState = true;
        dl.AutoPostBack = true;
        this.NumberOfControls++;
        dl.ID = "ControlID_" + this.NumberOfControls.ToString();

        using (I.DBEntities1 ctx = new I.DBEntities1())
        {
            dl.DataSource = ctx.Lk_PersonPersonAssocType.OrderBy(c => c.Assoc_Type);
            dl.DataValueField = "ID";
            dl.DataTextField = "Assoc_Type";
            dl.DataBind();
        }

        DynamicControlsHolder.Controls.Add(dl);
        DynamicControlsHolder.EnableViewState = true;

    }


    protected void createControls()   //postback, rely upon viewstate here
    {
        int count = this.NumberOfControls;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();
            dl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dlOnSelectedIndexChange);
            dl.AutoPostBack = true;

        using (I.DBEntities1 ctx = new I.DBEntities1())
        {

            dl.DataSource = ctx.Lk_PersonPersonAssocType.OrderBy(c => c.Assoc_Type);
            dl.DataValueField = "ID";
            dl.DataTextField = "Assoc_Type";
            dl.DataBind();

        }

        dl.ID = "ControlID_" + NumberOfControls.ToString();

        DynamicControlsHolder.Controls.Add(dl);

        }
    }
```